# Can someone example and give an example?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given an example of a function $f $ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } f(x)$   exists,  but   $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } f'(x)$  does not exist.

Comment: IMO $1/x^2sinx$ fit, as you can replace x by $1/t$

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}.
$$

Using the Squeeze Theorem, you can show that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0.
$$

However, its derivative
$$
f'(x) = 2\cos(x^2) - \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}
$$
never settles down as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: dont u think that derivative of ur example is not right?

Comment: Whoops.  I fixed the denominator of the second term.  That was a typo.  Good catch.